# C# how to sort list<T> and update to listview, the listview only show part

Tags: c#, listview, sorting

```cs
public class ListKeywords
{
    public int ID { set; get; }
    public string Keyword { set; get; }
    public string Language { set; get; }
    public int WordCount { set; get; }
} 

List<ListKeywords> keywordsList = new List<ListKeywords>();
// 
listview1.Add(new ListKeywords() { ID = keywordsList.Count+1, Keyword = line.Trim(), WordCount = countWords(line) });
```

i want to add 10000 ListKeywords item to ListKeywords, but i just want to display top 1000 item in listview1 control.

Now, if sort listview1 i want to sort all the item (ListKeywords ), not only sort top 1000 item in listview1.

How to do it ?

> Sorry my English is not very good

Comment: You want to ListKeywords to the keywordList. You want to add 10000 items and get only the top 1000, in order to bind them in the listview1 control. Right? What would be the criterion to get the top 1000?

Comment: i want sort by keywords or by ID.  when click listview, the listview1 control can be sorted.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort by keywrods then use this:

```
var top1000Items = keywordsList.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Keyword).Take(1000);
```

If you want to sord by ID then use this:

```
var top1000Items = keywordsList.OrderByDescending(x=>x.ID).Take(1000);
```

So if you have 10.000 items and and tier IDs start from 1 and finish to 10000, then if you sort by ID, the `top1000Items` would have Ids ranging from 9001 to 10000.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<ListKeywords> SortedList = SortedList.OrderBy(o=>o.ID).Take(1000).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just bind your listview to a property that does the work for you. Something like:

```
public List<ListKeywords> Top1000Sorted 
{
    get
    {
        return keywordsList.OrderBy(x => x.ID).Take(1000).ToList();
    }
}
```

And bind the ListView using:

```
listview1.ItemsSource = Top1000Sorted;
```

Comment: .NET 3.5 is not support ItemsSource properties

Comment: Actually it does, in WPF. I guess you're using Windows Forms. If you switch to DataGridView you might be able to use DataGridView.DataSource.

Answer (score 0):

Just use lists's `OrderBy` method prior to selecting the top 1000 objects.  Then `Take` the top 1000 entries.

So, something like this method:

```
public List<ListKeywords> SortByIdAndSelectRange(List<ListKeywords> list, int range)
{
    return list.OrderBy(x => x.ID).Take(range).ToList();
}
```

Use:

```
myList = SortAndSelectRange(myList, 1000);
```

You can modify that method further to decide what you want to sort by.

Here's a very crude sample showing the use of the above method:

```
class ListKeywords
{
    public int ID { set; get; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myList = new List<ListKeywords>();

        Random rnd = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3000; i++)
        {
            var entry = new ListKeywords() { ID = rnd.Next(3000, 9999) };
            myList.Add(entry);
        }

        myList = SortByIdAndReturnRange(myList, 1000);

        foreach (var entry in myList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(entry.ID);
        }
    }


    static List<ListKeywords> SortByIdAndReturnRange(List<ListKeywords> list, int range)
    {
        return list.OrderBy(x => x.ID).Take(range).ToList();
    }
}
```

Lastly, you can stack sorting:

```
myList.OrderBy(x => x.Param1).ThenBy(x => x.Param2).ThenBy(x => x.Param3) ... and so on.
```

I use that when I want to sort a list by date, and then every day to be sorted by time.